# Fourier transform on 1D bipartite lattice

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, fourier-transform, crystals

I have a 1-D lattice Hamiltonian like
$$
H=-t\sum_{\langle ij \rangle} (c^\dagger_i c_j + h.c.),
$$
I have to do its Fourier transform for 1-D bipartite lattice, I can think of two possible ways of doing but don't know whether both are correct or not. First one is like defining different creation and annihilation operators for odd and even sites. Let's define for odd sites $a$, $a^\dagger$ and for even sites $b$, $b^\dagger$, so
$$
H = t\sum_{\langle ij \rangle} (a^\dagger_i b_j + b^\dagger_j a_i)
$$
Now doing its Fourier transform:
$$
\begin{align*}
H &= \frac{1}{N}t\sum_{\langle nm \rangle}\sum_{p,k}\left(a^\dagger_pb_ke^{i(km-pn)} + b^\dagger_ka_pe^{-i(km-pn)}\right) \\
&= \frac{t}{N}\sum_{n}\sum_{p,k}\left(a^\dagger_pb_ke^{i(k(n+1)-pn)} + a^\dagger_pb_ke^{i(k(n-1)-pn)} + b^\dagger_ka_pe^{-i(k(n+1)-pn)} + b^\dagger_ka_pe^{-i(k(n-1)-pn)}\right) \\
&= \frac{t}{N}\sum_{n}\sum_{p,k}\left(e^{ik}a^\dagger_pb_ke^{i(kn-pn)} + e^{-ik}a^\dagger_pb_ke^{i(kn-pn)} + e^{-ik}b^\dagger_ka_pe^{-i(kn-pn)} + e^{ik}b^\dagger_ka_pe^{-i(kn-pn)}\right) \\
&= t\sum_{k}\left(e^{ik}a^\dagger_kb_k + e^{-ik}a^\dagger_kb_k + e^{-ik}b^\dagger_ka_k + e^{ik}b^\dagger_ka_k\right) \\
&= 2t\sum_{k}\left[\cos(k)a^\dagger_kb_k + \cos(k)b^\dagger_ka_k\right].
\end{align*}
$$
This leads to:
$$
\begin{align*}
H &= \sum_{k}\begin{pmatrix} a^\dagger_k & b^\dagger_k \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0& 2t\cos(k) \\ 2t\cos(k) & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a_k \\ b_k \end{pmatrix} 
\end{align*}
$$
**Here $k\in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ right? Because B.Z. will be halved? And $N=$no. of lattice sites.**

Another way is like defining things in terms of bonds in terms of lattice sites, let's say $I$ is the index of a bond centre lying between lattice sites $2i$(call it A) and $2i+1$ (call it B). Now,
$$
H= -t\sum_{\langle IJ \rangle} (c^\dagger_{I,A} c_{J,B} + h.c.)
$$
Now if I do F.T. I'll get
$$
\begin{align*}
H &= \sum_{k}\begin{pmatrix} c^\dagger_{k,A} & c^\dagger_{k,B} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0& t(1+e^{-2ik}) \\ t(1+e^{2ik}) & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} c_{k,A} \\ c_{k,B} \end{pmatrix} 
\end{align*}
$$
**and here also $k\in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, right? and while doing Fourier transform $N$ that we'll use will be number of bonds, not the lattice site right?**

Both these methods are equivalent or not? and the way $k$ is halved in both cases and different meanings of $N$ is fine or not?

Comment: $N$ should be the number of unit cells (i.e. the motifs that are repeated by translational symmetry), not the number of lattice sites. Equivalent Fourier conventions should give the same predictions for observables, but it seems your two Hamiltonians produce different eigenvalues.

Comment: @Anyon Sorry, missed a factor of 2 in the second Hamiltonian. Its corrected now.